# how to append an Image to request url in android

Tags: android, web-services, image-uploading, putimagedata

I have made an activity in that I am selecting a pic from camera or gallery and have to upload to server by appending its name and data to url,I have heard about to convert it to binary or "imageData" and append to requestURL to upload it over server.But I really dont have idea how to do that,Can anybuddy please help me what changes should i make in my code"?Please >..My code is as below:

```
My url is:http://yehki.epagestore.in//app_api/buying_request.php?customer_id=6&product_name=checkapi&category_id=1&expire_time=09-05-90&detail_desc=somedec&esti_ordr_qty=200&esti_ordr_qty_unit=1&filename=t1231he.jpg&image=" "
```

**main.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buying_request);

    InitializeView();
    productCategory.setOnClickListener(this);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);
    expTime.setOnClickListener(this);
    proImg.setOnClickListener(this);

    dateandtime = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
    header.back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });

    reqList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    queList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    viewReq.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            flag = 2;
            reqList.clear();
            iv_fav_menu.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_two_fav);

            callGetQuoteListAsyncTask();

            scr_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            quote_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rl_botm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            scr_post.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BuyingRequestDetailActivity.class);

            // getting ProductId from the tag...

            String buyReqID = reqList.get(position).get(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID);

            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::;;THE INTENT FOR THE resuest DETIALS ACTIVITY=================" + buyReqID);
            in.putExtra(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID, buyReqID);
            in.putExtra(Const.TAG_QUOTE_ID, quote_id);
            System.out.println("::::::::::::Buyer Id and Request Id::::::::;" + buyReqID + " ====>" + quote_id);
            startActivity(in);
        }

    });
    quoteList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuoteDetailActivity.class);

            // getting ProductId from the tag...

            reqID = queList.get(position).get(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID);
            quote_id = queList.get(position).get(Const.TAG_QUOTE_ID);
            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::;;THE INTENT FOR THE resuest DETIALS ACTIVITY=================" + reqID);
            in.putExtra(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID, reqID);
            in.putExtra(Const.TAG_QUOTE_ID, quote_id);
            System.out.println("::::::::::::Buyer Id and Request Id::::::::;" + reqID + " ====>" + quote_id);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    postReq.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            flag = 1;
            iv_fav_menu.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_one_fav);
            quote_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            scr_post.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rl_botm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            scr_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i;
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.tv_pro_cat:
        i = new Intent(BuyingreqActivity.this, ProCategoryActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 10);

        break;
    case R.id.tv_pro_exp_tym:

        DatePickerDailog dp = new DatePickerDailog(BuyingreqActivity.this, dateandtime, new DatePickerDailog.DatePickerListner() {

            @Override
            public void OnDoneButton(Dialog datedialog, Calendar c) {
                datedialog.dismiss();
                dateandtime.set(Calendar.YEAR, c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                dateandtime.set(Calendar.MONTH, c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                dateandtime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                expTime.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(c.getTime()));
            }

            @Override
            public void OnCancelButton(Dialog datedialog) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                datedialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dp.show();

        break;
    case R.id.btn_send:
        new postBuyingReqList().execute();

        break;
    case R.id.iv_img:
        showCustomeAlert2(BuyingreqActivity.this, "Yehki", "From Camera", "From Gallery");

        break;

    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void showCustomeAlert2(Context context, String title, String rightButton, String leftButton) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(BuyingreqActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_alert);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    final ImageView btn_lft = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.iv_left);
    final ImageView btn_rgt = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.iv_right);
    final Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancle);

    final TextView btn_left = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnLeft);
    final TextView btn_right = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnRight);

    btn_left.setText(leftButton);
    btn_right.setText(rightButton);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    btn_rgt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                System.out.println("=========== perform click ==============");
                String mediaStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath();

                fileName = "user_" + Pref.getValue(BuyingreqActivity.this, Const.PREF_USER_ID, 0) + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
                imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Const.DIR_USER + "/" + fileName));

                System.out.println(" PATH ::: " + imageUri);

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";

            }

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    btn_lft.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            // call android default gallery
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            // ******** code for crop image
            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
            intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);

            try {

                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}

void InitializeView() {
    iv_fav_menu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_fav_menu);
    viewReq = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_view);
    postReq = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_post);
    scr_post = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scr_post);
    scr_view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.scr_view);
    quote_view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.quote_view);
    quoteList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.quote_list);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.req_list);
    rl_botm = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_botm);
    header = (Header) findViewById(R.id.headerBuying);
    header.title.setText("Post Buying Request");
    proImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_img);
    productName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pro_name);
    productCategory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_pro_cat);
    expTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_pro_exp_tym);
    productDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pro_desc);
    estOrderQty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_est_qty);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

}

/*
 * getting buying request list...!!!
 */
private class GetBuyingReqList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BuyingreqActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        String query = "?customer_id=" + Pref.getValue(BuyingreqActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, "");
        query = query.replace(" ", "%20");
        viewURL = Const.API_BUYING_REQUEST_LIST + query;
        BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();

        System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::ADDRESS URL:::::::::::::::::" + viewURL);
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(viewURL, BackendAPIService.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        try {
            if (jsonStr != null) {

                jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                if (jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST)) {
                    System.out.println("::::::::::::::::true::::::::::::::::" + jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_LIST));
                    requestes = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST);

                    if (requestes != null && requestes.length() != 0) {
                        // looping through All Contacts

                        System.out.println(":::::::::::FLAG IN SUB:::::::::::" + flag);
                        for (int i = 0; i < requestes.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = requestes.getJSONObject(i);

                            String buyer_request_id = c.getString(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID);
                            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::MY buying request:::::::::::::" + buyer_request_id);
                            String subject = c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);
                            String date_modified = c.getString(Const.TAG_DATE_MODIFIED);
                            String expired_date = c.getString(Const.TAG_EXPIRY_DATE);
                            String quote_count = c.getString(Const.TAG_QUOTE_COUNT);
                            String buying_request_status = c.getString(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_STATUS);

                            HashMap<String, String> request = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            request.put(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID, buyer_request_id);
                            request.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, subject);
                            request.put(Const.TAG_DATE_MODIFIED, date_modified);
                            request.put(Const.TAG_EXPIRY_DATE, expired_date);
                            request.put(Const.TAG_QUOTE_COUNT, quote_count);
                            request.put(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_STATUS, buying_request_status);
                            reqList.add(request);
                            System.out.println("::::::::::::::::REQUEST IDS::::::::::::" + buyer_request_id);

                        }
                    }
                }

            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::got an error::::::::::::");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * 
         * */

        buyingRequestContent = new BuyingRequestAdapter(BuyingreqActivity.this, reqList);

        lv.setAdapter(buyingRequestContent);

    }

}

public void callGetQuoteListAsyncTask() {
    new GetBuyingReqList().execute();
}

/*
 * getting qoute List...!!!
 */
public class GetQuoteList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        queList.clear();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BuyingreqActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        scr_post.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        scr_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        quote_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        // String query = "?customer_id=" +
        // Pref.getValue(BuyingreqActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, "")
        // + "&buyer_request_id=23";
        String reqID = arg0[0];
        String query = "?customer_id=" + Pref.getValue(BuyingreqActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, "") + "&buyer_request_id=" + reqID;
        query = query.replace(" ", "%20");
        viewURL = Const.API_QUOTE_RECIEVED + query;
        BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();

        System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::ADDRESS URL:::::::::::::::::" + viewURL);
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(viewURL, BackendAPIService.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        try {
            if (jsonStr != null) {

                jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                if (jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST)) {
                    System.out.println("::::::::::::::::true::::::::::::::::" + jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_LIST));
                    requestes = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST);

                    if (requestes != null && requestes.length() != 0) {
                        // looping through All Contacts

                        System.out.println(":::::::::::FLAG IN SUB:::::::::::" + flag);
                        for (int i = 0; i < requestes.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = requestes.getJSONObject(i);

                            buyerID = c.getString(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID);
                            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::MY buying request:::::::::::::" + buyerID);
                            String product_name = c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);
                            String quote_id = c.getString(Const.TAG_QUOTE_ID);
                            String supplier_name = c.getString(Const.TAG_SUPPLIER_NAME);
                            String status = c.getString(Const.TAG_STATUS);

                            HashMap<String, String> quote = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            quote.put(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID, buyerID);
                            quote.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, product_name);
                            quote.put(Const.TAG_QUOTE_ID, quote_id);
                            quote.put(Const.TAG_EXPIRY_DATE, supplier_name);
                            quote.put(Const.TAG_QUOTE_COUNT, status);
                            queList.add(quote);
                            System.out.println(":::::::::::::Buyer request ID:" + buyerID);
                        }
                    }
                }

            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::got an error::::::::::::");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * 
         * */

        quoteAdapter = new QuoteAdapter(BuyingreqActivity.this, queList);

        quoteList.setAdapter(quoteAdapter);

    }

}

// ============================
/*
 * post Buying Request api()...!!!
 */
private class postBuyingReqList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BuyingreqActivity.this);

        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        postURL = Const.API_BUYING_REQUEST + "?customer_id=" + Pref.getValue(BuyingreqActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, "") + "&product_name=" + productName.getText().toString().trim()
                + "&category_id=" + id + "&expire_time=" + expTime.getText().toString() + "&detail_desc=" + productDesc.getText().toString().trim() + "&esti_ordr_qty="
                + estOrderQty.getText().toString().trim() + "&esti_ordr_qty_unit=1&filename=" + fileName + "&image=" + encodedImage;
        // Creating service handler class instance
        postURL = postURL.replace(" ", "%20");
        BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();

        System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::post buying request URL:::::::::::::::::" + postURL);
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(postURL, BackendAPIService.POST);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        try {
            if (jsonStr != null) {

                jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                if (jsonObj.get("status").equals("success")) {
                    flag = 0;
                }

            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::got an error::::::::::::");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Intent i;
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        if (flag == 0) {
            Utils.showCustomeAlertValidation(BuyingreqActivity.this, "Request Posted", "Yehki", "OK");
            clearViews();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(BuyingreqActivity.this, "Buying Request has not been posted", 0).show();
        }
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * 
         * */

    }

}

void clearViews() {
    productName.setText("");
    productDesc.setText("");
    estOrderQty.setText("");
    expTime.setText("Expiration Time");
    proImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimage);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE) { // for camera
        try {
            System.out.println("============= FILENAME :: " + fileName);
            if (new File(Const.DIR_USER + "/" + fileName).exists()) {
                performCrop();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == 2) { // for crop image
        try {
            if (data != null) {
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");

                Utils.createDirectoryAndSaveFile(thePic, Const.DIR_USER + "/" + fileName);

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thePic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
                // pro_pic.setImageBitmap(thePic);
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                Drawable dra = (Drawable) new BitmapDrawable(thePic);
                proImg.setImageDrawable(dra);
                proImg.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (data != null) {
            /*
             * fileName = Const.DIR_USER + "/" + "user_" +
             * Pref.getValue(ProfileActivity.this, Const.PREF_USER_ID, 0) +
             * "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
             */
            fileName = "user_" + Pref.getValue(BuyingreqActivity.this, Const.PREF_USER_ID, 0) + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";

            Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap photo = extras2.getParcelable("data");

            Utils.createDirectoryAndSaveFile(photo, Const.DIR_USER + "/" + fileName);

            String filePath = Const.DIR_USER + "/" + fileName;
            System.out.println("::::::::::::::::GALLERY PATH:::::::::::::" + filePath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
            encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
            ImageView picView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_img);

            picView.setImageBitmap(photo);

        }

    }
    if (requestCode == 10) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            id = data.getStringExtra("ID");
            name = data.getStringExtra("NAME");
            System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::On activity result:::::::::::" + id + "==========" + name);
            productCategory.setText(name);
        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}

private void performCrop() {
    try {

        System.out.println("============= AFTER FILENAME :: " + fileName);

        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Const.DIR_USER + "/" + fileName));
        String ImagePath = imageUri.toString().trim();

        try {
            imageInFile = new FileInputStream(ImagePath);
            byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) ImagePath.length()];
            imageInFile.read(imageData);

            // Converting Image byte array into Base64 String
            imageDataString = encodeImage(imageData);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 200);// 256
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 200);

        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 2);
    }

    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

        String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}

/*
 * CONVERT THE IMAGE TO DATA..!!!
 */
public static String encodeImage(byte[] imageByteArray) {
    return Base64.encodeToString(imageByteArray, 1);
}
```

}

**Logcat**

```
05-13 19:04:34.606: I/System.out(23172): :::::::::::::::::::post buying request URL:::::::::::::::::http://yehki.epagestore.in/app_api/buying_request.php?customer_id=41&product_name=juh7&category_id=4&expire_time=2014-07-13&detail_desc=uhuh&esti_ordr_qty=200&esti_ordr_qty_unit=1&filename=user__1399988051310.png&image=/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
05-13 19:04:34.606: I/System.out(23172): AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
05-13 19:04:34.606: I/System.out(23172): AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCACgAKADASIA
05-13 19:04:34.606: I/System.out(23172): AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA
05-13 19:04:34.606: I/System.out(23172): AAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3
05-13 19:04:34.606: I/System.out(23172): ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm
05-13 19:04:34.606: I/System.out(23172): p6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEA
05-13 19:04:34.606: I/System.out(23172): AwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx...and so one..!!!
```

Comment: hey you have web service for this task ?? and tell me what you have tried before  ??

Comment: @rahu Please see my updated code..I have tried as it.but it gives me "Illegal Argument exception",SO I think the bytestream not properly encoded

Comment: @RahulGupta Please see my updated code..I have tried as it.but it gives me "Illegal Argument exception",SO I think the bytestream not properly encoded

Comment: @RahulGupta-I have popsted Logcat...Please check it friend.!

Comment: i will check will provide you ans ok